# Start sh.exe (bash) with given path

Tags: command-line, bash, git, path

I need to start the git-bash (sh.exe) with a predefined path in a Windows environment.

For cmd.exe this can be done with a command like:

```
cmd.exe /K "cd /d {PATH_GOES_HERE}"
```

For powershell.exe this can be done with this command:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command "cd '{PATH_GOES_HERE}'"
```

But I could not manage to get that same with git-bash aka sh.exe. I tried stuff like ...

```
sh.exe --login -i -c "cd {PATH_GOES_HERE}"
```

... but I could not make it work.

The command line itself works, by entering ...

```
sh.exe --login -i -c "ls"
```

... I get the bash-colorized output of the directory

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a tip from **Michael D**, I installed Git with the feature "Git Bash Here". Then I looked up the way Git does it by browsing the registry at:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_shell\command
```

That gave me the command to use:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe "--cd=%1"
```

Where `%1` stands for the path provided by the Windows Explorer.

So all I had to do was to go for a command like:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe "--cd={PATH_GOES_HERE}"
```

Btw, no need to transform Windows paths to stuff like `/c/users/myuser/...`

That means I am not using **sh.exe** but **git-bash.exe** from now on.

Thanks mates.

Comment: Pay attention to skip backslashes at the end: it won't accept ´C:\Users\´ but ´C:\Users´ for example

Answer (score 1):

`bash` is reading the `.bashrc` file on start.

1. start `sh.exe --login`
2. create `.bashrc` file by entering `echo "cd c/Windows/system32/" > ~/.bashrc`
3. logout (Ctrl + D)
4. start `sh.exe --login`
5. enter `pwd`
   should be `c/Windows/system32/`

AFAIK windows is protecting the `\Program Files\` folder with the UAC. You might need to run `sh.exe` as admin, or consider to install git to `C:\git` instead (outside the program files folder).

Comment: I really appreciate that answer, but that seems not to be a reasonable way to go for me, I'm afraid. I don't have administrative priviledges and I don't want to edit configuration files just to init my bash session.

Comment: yeah `sh -c` is just running the command and exits after that.

Comment: I learned that, yeah 

Comment: when installing git on windows, it's gives you the `git bash here` with the right click in the win explorer

Comment: Might be, but I cannot use it like that, sorry. However, it would be interesting how this is done internally. Might take a look, thank you!

Comment: is there a reason why you need to be in that path? You could just add that path to your environment

Comment: You're the man - that tip was pure gold! But I think I'll go for my own answer, so that the next readers will see it. Thanks!